# Node.js issue with Math.log exiting immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, frontend, v8

I was doing some work with Gulp and pushed my tasks to our Windows 2008 R2 server where they strangely stopped working.

The tasks are just exiting at a certain point and return me to prompt.  Everything is working fine on my Windows 7 dev machine and on one Windows 2008 R2 server, so far the issue is only occuring on our development Windows 2008 R2 server

Through isolation, I was able to narrow it down to the module [Pretty bytes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-bytes) which uses Math.log in its calculation. I tried to use Math.log directly from node and I get the same result on that one server. It looks like Math.log is broken, however other Math functions work just fine.

Reproduction steps below:

Details:

```
2 different Windows 2008 R2 running in a VM (if that's important)
node v0.12.7

//nodemathtest.js
console.log(process.versions);
console.log("before");
console.log(Math.floor(2.2));
console.log(Math.log(10));
console.log("after");
```

Running `node mathlogtest.js`

On one my machine and on one Windows 2008 R2 server I get the expected result:

```
C:\>node mathlogtest.js
{ http_parser: '2.3',
  node: '0.12.7',
  v8: '3.28.71.19',
  uv: '1.6.1',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  modules: '14',
  openssl: '1.0.1p' }
before
2
2.302585092994046
after
```

On our development Windows server where the Gulp tasks are exiting prematurely I get this:

```
C:\>node mathlogtest.js
{ http_parser: '2.3',
  node: '0.12.7',
  v8: '3.28.71.19',
  uv: '1.6.1',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  modules: '14',
  openssl: '1.0.1p' }
before
2

C:\>
```

I can see that Math.log is causing Node to exit immediately back to prompt which is also what's happening from Gulp, I get kicked back to my prompt and the task is interrupted.

I'm not exactly sure where to look as I'm fairly new to Node.  From my understanding Node is using Chrome's V8 JS engine and `process.version` is returning exactly the same on each server.  I've tried to install .NET 4.5.1 and various C++ redistributable package to no avail.

Comment: Where's the "3" coming from?

Comment: My bad, the 3 was from testing Math.ceil(2.2) - edited to match example.

Comment: Did you try copying the binary from the working system to the non-working system and trying it that way as well?

Comment: Additionally, are there any running processes that differ between the two systems? Something (e.g. security software) that might be interrupting the process on the development machine? What does `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` show after the premature exit?

Comment: @mscdex tried the binary from the working system and got the same error.  echo errorlevel immediately after returns -1073741795 on the faulty server.  It returns as expected? 0 on the server where it works. There are various processes as both servers are used for web development but they are somewhat similar (IIS, MSSQL, etc.)

Comment: @jfrobishow That error code is a bit strange. Does that system have the latest Windows updates? If not, I would try updating first. If you still encounter the issue, you might try a debug version of the node binary (you may have to compile one yourself with `vcbuild debug nosign x64` after checking out the v0.12.7 source) which will (hopefully) show VC++ assertion errors and whatnot that would not otherwise not be displayed in release binaries.

Comment: @mscdex so I compiled my own debug version as you suggested and that one works fine no error!  My version of node was installed with Chocolatey so I thought it might have been corrupted, I re-installed it using the official installer and the same error occured again.  At least now I have a working version.  I'll submit this to the node mailing list to see.